# Cluster process blocking in Node.js/Express application

Tags: node.js

I am working on a Node.js application using Express framework and I use cluster to handle load. In testing I notice that if for some reason one of the processes is taking a long time to load, it affect other subsequent requests too. I made a simple test case for this:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7325816

running the example with "node app.js" and trying to load `http://localhost:8080/slow` (which has a blocking calculation taking several seconds) in one browser window and `http://localhost:8080/fast` immediately in another window, the latter also takes several seconds to load.

If I understand correctly, this is because the same process which is running the calculation is trying to process the new request: but how to avoid this?

Edit:

Here is output of HTTP requests running Siege after running /slow:

```
HTTP/1.1 200   0.01 secs:      89 bytes ==> GET  /fast
HTTP/1.1 200   6.32 secs:      89 bytes ==> GET  /fast
HTTP/1.1 200   0.01 secs:      89 bytes ==> GET  /fast
HTTP/1.1 200   6.84 secs:      89 bytes ==> GET  /fast
HTTP/1.1 200   0.00 secs:      89 bytes ==> GET  /fast
HTTP/1.1 200   7.41 secs:      89 bytes ==> GET  /fast
HTTP/1.1 200   0.00 secs:      89 bytes ==> GET  /fast
HTTP/1.1 200   9.04 secs:      89 bytes ==> GET  /fast
```

Edit 2:

Problem was with the latest Git version (v0.11.9-pre) of Node.js running on OSX: running current release v0.10.21 it works fine without transferring requests to the blocked process. Thanks @goten for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have several CPU cores  cluster should run several process. 
It's pretty well explain there http://rowanmanning.com/posts/node-cluster-and-express/

```
var http = require('http');
var cluster = require('cluster');
var express = require('express');

if(cluster.isMaster){
    //count the CPU
    var cpuCount = require('os').cpus().length;

    // Create a worker for each CPU
    for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
        cluster.fork();
    }
}
else{
    var app = express();
    var server = http.createServer(app);

    app.get('/slow', function(req, res){
        someSlowFunction();
    });
    app.get('/fast', function(req, res){
        someFasterFunction();
    });

    server.listen(3000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my example code is almost identical and is already running multiple processes. The problem is that if I have four processes in the cluster and I make first request to the slow function and make five additional requests before it finishes, one of the five goes to the slow process (ie. waiting for slow process to finishe) instead of using any of the other three free processes.

Comment: do you have the latest version of nodeJs because I run your program, it's working perfectly, 1 request with 3 concurrent on /slow and at the same time 10 request with 10 concurrent on /fast using siege, and I did not have any problem.

Comment: I'm running latest Node from Git (0.11.9-pre) on OSX. I added to the question my output for Siege.

Comment: try not to run nodejs under 0.XX.YY-pre. I was getting problems under OS X. Better download from there http://nodejs.org/download/ .

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, using the release version it works fine! I will update the question and give you the credits.

Answer (score 0):

node.js has is single threaded by nature.  It uses callbacks, but each of those callbacks is run on a single event loop.  So no matter how you configure you callbacks, eventually you are going to run into a situation where /slow has to run and will crowd out everything else until it is done.  This is because /slow is CPU intensive.  If it had some IO, then that IO could be done asynchronously.

There are a few newer threading options that you should try, creating a thread from the /slow function. See http://bjouhier.wordpress.com/2012/03/11/fibers-and-threads-in-node-js-what-for/, specifically https://github.com/xk/node-threads-a-gogo.

Threads-a-gogo has an example that closely matches yours at https://github.com/xk/node-threads-a-gogo/blob/master/examples/demo.js.